# multiple background images on top of each other

Tags: cytoscape.js

It seems like we can use multiple background images like below.

```
{
  'background-image': [
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/High_above_the_Cloud_the_Sun_Stays_the_Same.jpg',
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/Pigeon_silhouette_4874.svg/1000px-Pigeon_silhouette_4874.svg.png'
  ],
  'background-fit': 'cover cover',
  'background-image-opacity': 0.5
}
```

In this example, two images are simply merged as a single image since both have opacity 0.5. If I set the opacity to 1, I only see a single image. Instead, I want to show them both on top of each other.

On the below image, you can see that the node has a circular "person image" and another circular white-blue image writes "5"

[image: 2 images on top of each other]

Can I do this just by using [background-image](https://js.cytoscape.org/#style/background-image)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Below styles might help to add multiple images on a node with cytoscape.js styles

```
  'background-fit': 'none',
  'background-image': [
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/High_above_the_Cloud_the_Sun_Stays_the_Same.jpg',
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/Pigeon_silhouette_4874.svg/1000px-Pigeon_silhouette_4874.svg.png'
  ],
  'background-image-opacity': 1,
  'background-width': '100% 30%',
  'background-height': '100% 30%',
  'background-position-x': '0% 85%',
  'background-position-y': '0% 10%'
```

Also dynamically creating SVG image might be used to put multiple images on top of each other